# How to publish one post to multiple post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been looking all over the web, but I'm not having luck.

I'm trying to find a way to publish one post to a two or more post types.

Let me clarify.
I'm developing a magazine site, I've created multiple post types (with CPTUI), zone 1, zone 2, zone 3, and so on. Some post will be only on zone 1, but some of them will be more general, so I need to publish post 1 to zone 1 and zone 3.

There's something that can let me do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating data is almost always a bad idea. This would mean if you post "Hello Wurld!" to Zone 1, 2, and 3 - You'll need to update that post to "Hello World!" in all 3 zones.

WordPress has a specific functionality for categorizing post types together called [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). In your instance, I'd evaluate whether using a Taxonomy called "Zone" with the terms "Zone 1", "Zone 2", "Zone 3", etc. would suffice on a single post type. (Think of taxonomy terms basically as categories).

If you decide you don't want to or *can't* heed this advice, you can make use of WordPress' [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook and call [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) inside of it with a copy of the current `$post_id`'s information, wrapped inside your logic to determine which "zones" it should be posted to